# Combining errors given standard deviation

Tags: statistics

> I find the mass of liquid in a container by using
>
> > mass of liquid = mass of (container+liquid) - mass of container
>
> My measurements are subject to an error with mean zero and standard deviation 0.7g. Find the standard deviation of the error in the calculated mass of the liquid.

Is this to do with linear combination of standard deviations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variance(mass of liquid) = Variance(mass of (container+liquid)) + Variance(mass of container) if the measurements of mass of (container+liquid) and mass of container are independent.